# Why does Xcode report "Variable 'tuple.0' used before being initialized" after I've assigned all elements of a Swift tuple?

Tags: swift

I want to assign the 3 numbers in an array to the 3 elements of a tuple using a `for` loop. The following function seems to do the trick, but Xcode errors as soon as I try to reference the (seemingly) fully assigned tuple. Am I doing something wrong?

```
typealias Triple = (Int, Int, Int)
func createTuple() -> Triple
{
    var tuple: Triple
    let r = [8, 6, 3]

    for i in 0..<r.count {
        switch(i) {
        case 0: tuple.0 = r[i]
        case 1: tuple.1 = r[i]
        case 2: tuple.2 = r[i]
        default : break
        }
    }
    return tuple // Xcode says "Variable 'tuple.0' used before being initialized
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem of determining whether a variable can be guaranteed to have been assigned or not is not decidable for the general case. This can be proven by a transformation on the halting problem. If you want to know more about that, I suggest you post a question on the Computer Science stack exchange site.

The Swift compiler approximates the solution to this problem by handling specific cases. Your case is not one of those handled by the Swift compiler (yet)?

If you just want to assign the triple, you can do this:

```
typealias Triple = (Int, Int, Int)
func createTriple() -> Triple {
    return (8, 6, 3)
}
```

If you want to assign it from an array, it's a lot simpler without the loop and switch (for the case of just 3 components)

```
typealias Triple = (Int, Int, Int)
func createTriple(from array: [Int]) -> Triple {
    guard array.count > 3 else {
       fatalError("Can't create a triple from less than 3 elements")
    }
    return (array[0], array[1], array[2])
}
```

Comment: Having to accept only one "correct" answer leaves me feeling somewhat dissatisfied here since both answers provided useful information in this case. In any event Alexander adding an additional code snippet is a helpful reminder to make better use of `guard` statements for sanity checking in my coding. But thanks to both of you!

Comment: Might I ask why you want to be making a function to creating triples? This is likely a home-made version of just using a strict with a regular initializer

Comment: I've been exploring generating and consuming an array of tuples as one way of producing the data used in a program I'm writing. My createTriple() function is an extremely simplified version of a function that's much more complicated. That said, after looking at the pros and cons of it, I'm thinking I'm going to generate an array of arrays instead. That seems to give me a lot more flexibility in what I need to do. (And could you explain what you mean by "using a strict with a regular initializer"? I don't understand.)

Comment: That sounds like a job for a struct. Triples are more weakly typed (e.g. your triple is the same as my `(Int, Int, Int)`,  or any other, for that matter. They also can't have instance methods or conform to protocols

Comment: A struct? Thank you! :-)

Comment: Do you know any programming languages?

Answer (score 1):

Although your code covers all three elements of the tuple, Xcode can't be certain that this is true. Between the loop and the `switch`, Xcode can't be certain that you're actually assigning to each element in `tuple`. Maybe the loop won't run enough times, or maybe the `switch` won't hit every case. You can see that they're all covered, but Xcode isn't quite sure.

You should either (a) assign default values to `tuple`, or (b) if defaults don't make sense, change `Triple` to contain three optional values, i.e.

```
typealias Triple = (Int?, Int?, Int?)
```